# Origin of subviews relative to parent UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, subview

I'm having a hell of a time positioning two subviews within their parent view. They are intended to comprise a rudimentary animated bar chart, and the animation part seems to be working well. Likewise, the corresponding bars appear to be accurately reflecting the data.

However, I'm trying to base the origin of the the two views on the lower edge of the parent view (the gray area in the screenshot), and the result seems random. I expect it's not really random, but I haven't been able to pin it down.

Here's the code:

```
-(void) makeBarChart
{
RiserBar *thisRiser;

for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
{
    thisRiser = [[RiserBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    thisRiser.tag = i+1;
    [self.chartView addSubview:thisRiser];
//    [self placeAndAnimateThisBar];
}

int barWidth = self.chartView.bounds.size.width /((2 * 2) -1);
int focusBarEndHeight = (self.chartView.bounds.size.height-20) * (focusActivityPercent / 100);
int benchmarkBarEndHeight = (self.chartView.bounds.size.height-20) * (benchmarkActivityPercent / 100);

for (thisRiser in self.chartView.subviews)
{
    switch (thisRiser.tag)
    {
        case 1:
        { [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                                  delay:.2
                                options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                             animations:^
             {
                 thisRiser.frame = CGRectMake(20, self.chartView.frame.origin.y, barWidth, 0);
                 thisRiser.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                 thisRiser.frame = CGRectMake(20, self.chartView.frame.origin.y, barWidth, -focusBarEndHeight);
                 thisRiser.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
             }
                             completion:^(BOOL finished)
             {
                 NSLog(@"Done!");
             }];
        }
            break;
        case 2:
        {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                                  delay:.2
                                options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                             animations:^
             {
                 thisRiser.frame = CGRectMake(barWidth + 40, self.chartView.frame.origin.y, barWidth, 0);//load frame from data
                 thisRiser.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                 thisRiser.frame = CGRectMake(barWidth + 40, self.chartView.frame.origin.y, barWidth, -benchmarkBarEndHeight);
                 thisRiser.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
             }
                             completion:^(BOOL finished)
             {
                 NSLog(@"Done!");
             }];
        }
            break;
        case 3:
            //do something to the view
            break;
            //and so on...
        default:
            break;
    }
}

}
```

and the resulting screenshot:

[image]

I should mention that the intent is for both the red and blue bar to originate at the bottom of the gray parent view and rise. It's not entirely clear to me why I have to reverse the polarity of the `.height`property to achieve this. And why is the origin somewhere near the middle of the parent view, given this code?

Can someone please point out my mistake(s)?

Thanks!

**Edit, pursuant to the gentle guidance of @Rob in Answer 2:**

Here is the change to the relevant part of my code, influenced also by the info in [**this slideshow**](http://www.slideshare.net/onoaonoa/cs193p-lecture-5-view-animation), which I highly recommend to anyone who, like me, prefers pictures to verbose explanations:

```
switch (thisRiser.tag)
{
    case 1:
    { [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                              delay:.2
                            options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^
         {
             thisRiser.frame = CGRectMake(20, self.chartView.frame.size.height, barWidth, 0);
             thisRiser.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
             thisRiser.frame = CGRectMake(20, self.chartView.frame.size.height, barWidth, -focusBarEndHeight);
             thisRiser.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished)
         {
             NSLog(@"Done!");
         }];
    }
        break;
    case 2:
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                              delay:.2
                            options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^
         {
             thisRiser.frame = CGRectMake(barWidth + 40, self.chartView.frame.size.height, barWidth, 0);//load frame from data
             thisRiser.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
             thisRiser.frame = CGRectMake(barWidth + 40, self.chartView.frame.size.height, barWidth, -benchmarkBarEndHeight);
             thisRiser.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished)
         {
             NSLog(@"Done!");
         }];
    }
        break;
    case 3:
        //do something to the view
        break;
        //and so on...
    default:
        break;
}
```

And here's what it looks like now (the differences in bar height pictured is due to different data):

[image]

Thanks again, Rob!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several lines similar to the following:

```
thisRiser.frame = CGRectMake(20, self.chartView.frame.origin.y, barWidth, -focusBarEndHeight);
```

It doesn't make sense to use the `frame.origin.y` of the `chartView` in the context of setting the frame for its subviews. One has nothing to do with the other. The `frame` of the riser is relative within the `chartView`, irrespective of the `origin` of `chartView`.

If you want `thisRiser` to be at the bottom of `chartView` with a height of `focusBarEndHeight`, I'd probably do something like:

```
thisRiser.frame = CGRectMake(20, self.chartView.frame.size.height - focusBarEndHeight, barWidth, focusBarEndHeight);
```

Comment: Thanks Rob. Not quite clear on your statement that "The frame of the riser is relative within the chartView..." Relative to what? Please correct me, but I think of a subview as a PostIt note stuck on a window, with its position determined by the position of the window. Clearly not, by your answer, but a quick look at the docs didn't resolve the issue. I'll study more, but if you've got time, an illustration would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Would have tried your suggestion, but am away from my MBP at the moment.

Comment: @TimJones Using your "PostIt" note analogy, the PostIt's `frame` is its position within a window pane. But the window's `frame` is an indication of where the sash is (i.e. is the window open or closed). But your position of the PostIt (i.e. the riser) is referencing the `frame.origin.y` (i.e. how open the window is) of the window (i.e. the `chartView`). The position of the PostIt has nothing to do with how open the window is. You just want it at the bottom of the window pane, and thus you only need to know the height of the window pane and the height of the PostIt.

Answer (score 0):

the subviews's actual position is also depend upon the autoresizingmask of parent. 
you need to consider the same as well while positioning your subviews or you can

Comment: Thanks, Sam. I'll look into the autoresizing aspect. Please see update above for solution to my immediate problem.